# Need default PPT template to load across all computers in org

Tags: applescript, python-pptx, dmg

I want my company template to load as the "blank presentation" in PPT when I load the program. How can I do this?

How do I create a .dmg in composer on MACs?

I tried to replace file in default temp folder and it didnt work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to make a template for PPT that is deployed across the company

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `Presentation()` is the template file. It defaults to one I don't like. Assuming your company really is using python-pptx this should meet your (first) need.

Comment: Is it possible to deploy to all macs?

Comment: Add this was tagged with python-pptx I guess deploying python-pptx and the appropriate script to all systems is a standard matter of software distribution / management.